# Version hierarchy in Jira queries

Tags: jira

I would like to configure versions in Jira in a hierarchy, so that search fixVersion=A also find issues with fixVersion equal to children version.

For a concrete example, I have versions like "Release 10", "Release 10 - Integration Build 1" and "Release 10 - Sprint 1", logically nested in each other. I would like search for fixVersion="Release 10" to return issues having any of these 3 values.

I know that I can assign 3 fixVersion values to each issue, but that's becoming rather tedious. I also know that I can search for 3 values of fixVersion, but it is also becoming rather tedious for one-off searches. Also, Jira's Greenhopper plugin has version hierarchy, but Jira core appears not to care a bit. Finally, fixVersion field does not allow string operations, so I cannot fuzzy match it against "Release 10".

Is there any trick I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "in" operator to make the query lighter.
e.g.
fixVersion in ("August release", "Aug-Sprint 1", "Aug-Sprint 2")

Or if you're using the Rapid Board which creates a new custom field called "Sprint", you could use the ">=" operator.  This looks to be a bit tetchy still, but then we're still on beta and haven't yet upgraded to GH v5.10
e.g.
Sprint >= "1" or Sprint >= "2" etc, will find all versions later than x.

Comment: The problem with "in" is that everybody would have to type the list of all versions by hand for any new searches -- and there does not seem to be a way to declare some macro to reuse it.

Comment: Regarding RapidBoard, I'm an actually testing it right now. I did not know it has a custom field called "Sprint" -- it sounds bizarre...

Comment: Looks to be that the Rapid Board's "Sprint" field is the way forward avoiding overloading (again) the fixVersion field. Running custom queries in Jql on this field is unreliable (at least in the beta release of labs / v5.9) as you need to know the index number of the "Sprint" rather than the sprint name; likewise in the database this becomes tricky as it seems to be referenced in the jiraevents table only.